# fmod() is not giving expected answer

Tags: c++

i am begginner in c++
below is my code ,I am using fmod(),in which the value of k should be 0.23 but it is giving it 0

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int k;
 k=fmod(234.23,3);
 cout<<"k="<<k<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

I am using codeblock.

Is it a compiler problem  ?

Comment: please use float instead of int for printing the correct value

Comment: As a beginner do you imagine that you are so lucky to spot a problem with the compiler?

Comment: `int` cannot represent `0.23`. You need a `float` or `double` value type.

Comment: In 99.9% of the cases it is not a compiler problem, so it shouldn't be your first thought

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the result to a  variable of type `int`, and `int` by its very nature can only represented integer numbers.

You need to use a floating-point type, such as `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 1):

You must use float instead of int for  k. An integer can only hold exact numbers, but no fractions. For this use, float or double.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a strongly typed language.

The result of `fmod(234.23, 3)` is 0.23, but you use an `int` to store it, so 0.23 is converted to a integer 0.

You should declare as `float k;`